# Is there a way to only allow dragging a sliderInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to fix the range in a shiny sliderInput such that it may only be dragged left or right, keeping the same range always. In the example below, the range is always kept to 10 but any range of 10 may be selected, e.g. 71-81 etc. Is it possible?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "foo",
    label = "Select Range",
    min = 0,
    max = 100,
    value = c(50, 60),
    step = 1,
    dragRange = T
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "foo",
    label = "Select Range",
    min = 0,
    max = 100,
    value = c(50, 60),
    step = 1,
    dragRange = T
  ))

server = function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$foo[1], {
    if (input$foo[1]<=90) mnval <- input$foo[1]
    else mnval = 90
    mxval = input$foo[1] + 10 
    updateSliderInput(session, "foo", min =0,max=100, value = c(mnval,mxval))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```